# Set up alias, function and enviroment variables for a device I'm using SSH to login to

Tags: shell, ssh, yocto, bitbake, busybox

My work consists of developing code that runs on a embedded device running Linux. Sometimes I need to use SSH to login to the device and run some commands. Some of those commands are long and hard to remember.

My question is how can I setup a configuration (like .bashrc or .zshrc) for the shell? The device is flashed often so I need a solution that works after flashing the device. The device is developed running the Yocto project and the shell is BusyBox.

I do realize that I can install a file and source it, however I want something more elegant. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is likely to get opinion-based answers. Where's your code so far?

Comment: Hard to imagine a solution more *elegant* that `source`ing a file.  Enumerate the options even on a fully-formed system (not busybox), what would you use there that is not available on busybox? Script any repeating tasks and then maybe make a script-of-scripts for really labor intensive but common problems? After a while they will be 2nd nature and they will fly off your fingers. Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm, it is possible to `source` a local file onto the remote with `ssh`. I've seen Q/A here about doing that (and have done that myself in a work environment). OR you can make local functions that call `ssh user@host "some list of commands to execute remotely"` sort of things. Good luck.

Comment: I have not written any code but alias that I would like is for example sc=systemctl, cdx= "/path/to/a/folder".

Comment: On a fully-formated system I would try editing/creating the .bashrc that automatically be sourced when logging in the the system. To my understanding the busybox shell does not source a file when being started. @shellter what do you mean with script-of-scripts?

Comment: @shellter, I have tried searching for what you suggest the in second comment however most searches lead me to other questions being answers, I'm not 100% shore how to search for what I want. But maybe the best way is to do function or alias on my host machine like: `ssh user@host "all my alias; /bin/sh || some command that keeps logged in"`. Thanks for the helpful suggestion.

Comment: script-of-scripts= 'masterScript calls `setupScript;scriptA;scriptB;specialCaseScript;cleanupScript`. Yes, busybox is the big roadblock here. Hm.. I could be misremembering now (10yrs practically). I would do something like `ssh user@remote 'myFunc(){echo "inside myFunc $@"}; myFunc arg1 arg2` and execute work remotely like that, but it didn't really set me up with defined functions so I could continue working on the remote machine from the CLI. I'm almost sure I have seen a solution for that, but I've been here for years now......

Comment: It will help your chances to get a solution from readers if you move the information in your comments regarding needs, defintions and research into the body of your message, and then delete as many unneeded comments as possible. (I'll delete or rewrite my comments based on your improvements.) Good luck.

Comment: You could add `debug-tweaks` as EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES which set root login and disable password. Or you could install and use `sshpass` which is a noninteractive ssh password provider.

Comment: So I have found a solution that I like more however have not got all working. Apparently there is two files that dose what I want `/etc/sshrc` or `~/.ssh/rc` that can be used, more info look at `man sshd`. So my thoughts is some package in bitbake install the `/etc/sshrc`. But I have not got everything working, alias, variables functions are not exported shell but i know it have been executed, are not sure whats wrong.